# Regexp doesn't work for specific special characters in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, special-characters

I can't get rid of the special character **¤** and **❤** in a string:

```
$word = 'cɞi¤r$c❤u¨s';
$word =~ s/[^a-zöäåA-ZÖÄÅ]//g;
printf "$word\n";
```

On the second line I try to remove any **non alphabetic** characters from the string `$word`. I would expect to get the word *circus* printed out but instead I get:

```
ci�rc�us
```

The *öäå* and *ÖÄÅ* in the expression are just normal characters in the Swedish alphabet that I need included.

Comment: Which perl version are you working with? Unicode support was gradually added and refined. Try to work with at least 5.12, and look at choroba's answer. `perl -v` to print out the version. [Manual for perl unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html)

Comment: Why do experienced programmers keep changing the questions? Now no user of my (low)experience is ever going to find the answer to his question.

Comment: I, too, find the edit too aggressive. It's good that the unicode tag was added now, though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the characters are in your source code, be sure to `use utf8`. If they are being read from a file, `binmode $FILEHANDLE, ':utf8'`.

Be sure to read [`perldoc perlunicode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html).

Comment: I think the encoding is correct as I can `printf 'cɞi¤r$c❤u¨söäå';` without problem. The problem comes in when I run the regular expression. Removing the **öäå** from the regexp solves the problem but then I can't use those characters in my string :/

Comment: You can print the string even without `use utf8`, but in such a case, Perl is printing _bytes_, not _characters_. That's also why it does not recognise the characters in the regex. Have you read `perlunicode`?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: add use utf8; to make sure your literal string in the source code are interepreted as utf8, that includes the content of the test string, and the content of the regexp.

Long answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use Encode;

my $word = 'cɞi¤r$c❤u¨s';

foreach my $char (split //, $word) {
    print ord($char) . Encode::encode_utf8(":$char ");
}

my $allowed_chars = 'a-zöäåA-ZÖÄÅ';

print "\n";

foreach my $char (split //, $allowed_chars) {
    print ord($char) . Encode::encode_utf8(":$char ");
}

print "\n";

$word =~ s/[^$allowed_chars]//g;

printf Encode::encode_utf8("$word\n");
```

Executing it without utf8:

```
$ perl utf8_regexp.pl
99:c 201:É 158: 105:i 194:Â 164:¤ 114:r 36:$ 99:c 226:â 157: 164:¤ 117:u 194:Â 168:¨ 115:s 
97:a 45:- 122:z 195:Ã 182:¶ 195:Ã 164:¤ 195:Ã 165:¥ 65:A 45:- 90:Z 195:Ã 150: 195:Ã 132: 195:Ã 133: 
ci¤rc¤us
```

Executing it with utf8:

```
$ perl -Mutf8 utf8_regexp.pl
99:c 606:ɞ 105:i 164:¤ 114:r 36:$ 99:c 10084:❤ 117:u 168:¨ 115:s 
97:a 45:- 122:z 246:ö 228:ä 229:å 65:A 45:- 90:Z 214:Ö 196:Ä 197:Å 
circus
```

Explanation:

The non-ascii characters that you are typing into your source code are represented by one than more byte. Since your input is utf8 encoded. In a pure ascii or latin-1 terminal the characters would've been one byte.

When not using utf8 module, perl thinks that each and every byte you are inputting is a separate character, like you can see when doing the splitting and printing each and every individual character. When using the utf8 module, it treats the combination of several bytes as one character correctly according to the rules of utf8 encoding.

As you can see by coinscidence, some of the bytes that the swedish characters are made up of match with some of the bytes that some of the characters in your test string are made up of, and they are kept. Namely: the ö which in utf8 consists of 195:Ã 164:¤ - The 164 ends up as one of the characters you allow and it passes thru.

The solution is to tell perl that your strings are supposed to be considered as utf-8.

The encode_utf8 calls are in place to avoid warnings about wide characters being printed to the terminal. As always you need to decode input, and encode output according to the character encoding that input or output is supposed to handle/operate in.

Hope this made it clearer.

Comment: Blah, sorry for having an overlapping answer. Feel free to delete or downvote this if you want ;-/

Answer (score -8):

As [pointed out by choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8270090/50776), adding this in the beginning of the perl script solves it:

```
use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

where `use utf8` lets you use the special characters correctly in the regular expression and `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")` lets you output the special characters correctly on the shell.

Comment: This is what choroba already suggested. Why do you provide a copy of his answer? Instead reward choroba with the "answer" (and also upvote him) (and then delete your own answer)

Comment: Because my answer is more pragmatic. I don't try to compete with him. I try to elaborate for future users that get stack on the same problem. The more answers the better in my opinion.

Comment: @Pithikos, you could just add it as a minor comment to his answer, especially if it showed you the way.

Comment: A minor comment when it's more lengthy than his answer? I don't see why such a fuzz. His answer wasn't satisfying enough for me. I still haven't solved my problem so I can't see why I am **forced** to accept it.

Comment: Your answer raises the exact two points that choroba already brought to your attention. It is fair to say that chorobas answer deserves an edit, and you can comment on that. But to claim his answer as yours is wrong. Btw, in your own answer you state that "this...solves it" and repeat chorobas code - that's why I think he deserves the answer checkmark.

Comment: I didn't claim his answer as mine. I would edit his answer if I had the privilege and accept it. However for a beginner like me it's hard to understand what he is talking about. Didn't even understand that `use utf8` was a code segment. It looked to me like he was pointing me to use utf8, something I couldn't translate to anything meaningful as I don't know how to "use utf8". It's not pedagogic to expect beginners to understand your jargon.